# Inserting a Date in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am wanting to insert a Date (as data type of TEXT) in SQLite. This is what I have setup:

```
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS practice_data(date TEXT, distance REAL, duration REAL, avg_pace REAL)')

date = str(input('Enter DATE (i.e. 2016-01-10): '))
distance = float(input('Enter TOTAL DISTANCE RAN (i.e 2.11): '))
duration = float(input('Enter TOTAL DURATION (i.e. 20.34): '))
avg_pace = float(input('Enter AVERAGE PACE (i.e. 10.44): '))

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO practice_data(date,distance,duration,avg_pace) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})".format(date, distance, duration, avg_pace))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()


create_table()
data_entry()
```

When I run the program it works fine. But when I open the SQLite Browser, the Date Column will not be correct. For example, if I input "2016-11-06" it will enter in "1999". For some reason it is assumming that the ' - ' are subtraction. Even though I have specified that date has a data type of TEXT.

I have seen that SQLite has a datetime option, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems, neither of which is due to SQLite.

In Python 2 this line:

```
date = str(input('Enter DATE (i.e. 2016-01-10): '))
```

results in `date` being assigned 1999 if you enter `2016-11-06`, and this is because Python 2 evaluates the input.

There are 2 solutions:

- Use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). `raw_input()` will return a string without evaluation:

  ```
  >>> n = input('? ')
  ? 1+2+3+4
  >>> n
  10
  >>> n = raw_input('? ')
  ? 1+2+3+4
  >>> n
  '1+2+3+4'
  ```
- Use Python 3

**EDIT**

Since you are using Python 3 the above does not apply.

The other problem is due to the way that you construct the query using string formatting:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO practice_data(date,distance,duration,avg_pace) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})".format(date, distance, duration, avg_pace))
```

This executes the query:

```
INSERT INTO practice_data(date,distance,duration,avg_pace) VALUES (2016-11-06, 1, 2, 3)
```

and SQLite will evaluate `2016-11-06` and then insert the result.

You could solve this by quoting the text fields like this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO practice_data(date,distance,duration,avg_pace) VALUES ('{}', {}, {}, {})".format(date, distance, duration, avg_pace))
```

but you shouldn't as it can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Instead of string formatting use parameterised queries:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO practice_data(date,distance,duration,avg_pace) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (date, distance, duration, avg_pace))
```

This uses place holders (`?`) for the fields, and the db engine will perform safe substitutions, properly quoting and escaping values as required.

Comment: I am using Python3.5 currently. I went ahead and changed the input() to raw_input() and ran it in Python 2.7. But I still get the same result of it interpreting the ' - ' as subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Python 2.x, because in 2.x `input` evaluates the input string (2016-11-6 == 1999).

You want to use `raw_input` instead (for 3.x you should use `input`)

Comment: I am using Python3.5 currently. I went ahead and changed the `input()` to `raw_input()` and ran it in Python2. But I still get the same result of it interpreting the ' - ' as subtraction.